# Prove that $A_{1} + A_{2}$ is a subspace of $V$ and contains $A_{1}\cup A_{2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A_{1}, A_{2}\subseteq V$ be subspaces and $A_{1} + A_{2} = \{a_{1} + a_{2} \mid (a_{1}, a_{2}) \in A_{1}\times A_{2}\}$.
Prove that

(a) $A_{1} + A_{2}$ is a subspace of $V$ and contains $A_{1}\cup A_{2}$.

(b) If $A\subseteq V$ is a subspace containing $A_{1} \cup A_{2}$, then $A$ contains $A_{1} + A_{2}$.

I'm not really sure where to start, other than write down the 3 conditions of a subspace:

1. Contains zero vector
2. Closed under addition
3. Closed under scalar multiplication

for (a) all I've managed to get down is that 0 + 0 = 0 to satisfy the condition that it contains the zero vector (is this even correct?).

I'm having a tough time trying to interpret the data that is given. Not entirely sure what $A_{1}\cup A_{2}$ means or $A_{1}\times A_{2}$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $A_1 \cup A_2 = \{v \in V \mid v \in A_1 \text{ or } v \in A_2\}$.

Comment: "*Not entire sure what $A_1\cup A_2$ means or $A_1\times A_2$*"  That's pretty critical information.  Without knowing what they mean you can't even read the problem, much less solve it.  Given sets $X$ and $Y$ you have $X\cup Y$ is the set of elements in at least one of (*possibly both*) $X$ or $Y$.  For example $\{1,2\}\cup \{2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$.  Next, $X\times Y = \{(x,y)~:~x\in X,~y\in Y\}$ is the set of all pairs you can make where the first element of each pair is from $X$ and the second of each pair from $Y$.  For example $\{1,2\}\times \{3,4,5\}=\{(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)\}$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing some understanding of basic set theory and set notation, so I would suggest you look for an introduction to that. To cover the parts that are necessary for this question, here are the parts you've said you don't recognise:

- $A \cup B$ is the *union* of sets $A$ and $B$, and is the set of all elements contained in either of them, i.e. $A \cup B = \{x : x \in A \mbox{ or } x \in B\}$. There is a companion operation, $A \cap B$, which is the *intersection* of $A$ and $B$, which contains all elements that are common between them, i.e. $A \cap B = \{x : x \in A \mbox{ and } x \in B\}$.
- $A \times B$ is the *Cartesian product* of $A$ and $B$, and it contains ordered pairs of elements, i.e. $A \times B = \{(a, b) : a \in A \mbox{ and } b \in B\}$

So in other words $A_1 + A_2$ is being defined as the set made from adding a vector in $A_1$ to a vector in $A_2$, and you are being asked to prove that (1) this is a subspace of $V$, (2) it contains every element of $A_1 \cup A_2$ (which means it contains every element of $A_1$ and also every element of $A_2$), and finally (3) it is the smallest such subspace, because it is itself a subspace of any other subspace that satisfies (1) and (2).

Comment: Okay thank you, this is all very helpful! I have another question: When I am trying to prove that it is closed under addition, I am not trying to prove that what is on the left (w1 + w2) is equal to what is on the right (w1,w2), right? What I've tried is: w1 +w2 = (a1,b1) + (a2,b2) = (a1+a2 , b1+b2). This is what I thought to do but I think I'm way off from what I should be trying to do.

Comment: The elements of $A_1 + A_2$ are *not* pairs, they are single vectors, and you shouldn't actually have to use the pair notation in your proof. If you want to refer to a vector $v$ in $A_1 + A_2$, then you should be saying that $v = v_1 + v_2$ where $v_1 \in A_1$ and $v_2 \in A_2$. (You can equivalently say $(v_1, v_2) \in A_1 \times A_2$, but it's not necessary and probably less helpful.)

Comment: To prove that it's closed under addition, you want to show that $v, w \in A_1 + A_2 \implies v + w \in A_1 + A_2$, so you should start by writing $v$ and $w$ as sums of vectors from the two component spaces, and use that to find a way to write $v + w$ similarly.